# All Public Keys are missing Xubuntu/Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, updates, xubuntu

After installing Xubuntu/Xfce desktop environments in my Ubuntu 14.04 64bit installation, I now get a list of missing Public Keys and errors when running an update.

I noticed in Synaptic Package Manage ALL the ubuntu keys are missing. In the list there is no software that has a Public Key.

The same issue whether I login the Unity or Xubuntu environments

```
pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:security-4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

*I do not think this is duplicated because none of the solutions have worked here and I ahve ALL keys missing?*

```
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Fetched 52.4 MB in 1min 16s (689 kB/s)                                         
W: GPG error: http://download.mono-project.com wheezy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A6A19B38D3D831EF
W: GPG error: http://deb.opera.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 517590D9A8492E35
W: GPG error: http://download.mono-project.com wheezy-apache24-compat InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A6A19B38D3D831EF
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release: Unknown error executing gpgv
W: GPG error: http://deb.opera.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 517590D9A8492E35
W: GPG error: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: Unknown error executing gpgv
W: GPG error: http://repo.vivaldi.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY CEC384A8BF1700F8
W: GPG error: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A040830F7FAC5991
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A040830F7FAC5991
W: GPG error: http://linux.dropbox.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FC918B335044912E
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A040830F7FAC5991
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A040830F7FAC5991
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: Unknown error executing gpgv
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: Unknown error executing gpgv
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release: Unknown error executing gpgv
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: Unknown error executing gpgv
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E131728675254D99
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E131728675254D99
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E131728675254D99
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E131728675254D99
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E131728675254D99
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E131728675254D99
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E131728675254D99
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E131728675254D99
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E131728675254D99
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E131728675254D99
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E131728675254D99
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E131728675254D99
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E131728675254D99
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E131728675254D99
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E131728675254D99
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E131728675254D99
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: Unknown error executing gpgv
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: Unknown error executing gpgv
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7274A4DAE80D6BF5
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A80C8DFE23A187B2
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 241FE6973B765FAE
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5AF549300FEB6DD9
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_i18n_Translation-en is not what the server reported 4089144 5062829
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_i18n_Translation-en is not what the server reported 5062829 10874183
W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried:

using the  FIX features in Y PPA Manager

**also this**

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 16126D3A3E5C1192 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 517590D9A8492E35 A6A19B38D3D831EF CEC384A8BF1700F8 A040830F7FAC5991 FC918B335044912E E131728675254D99 40C18E9EC07EE05F 7274A4DAE80D6BF5
A80C8DFE23A187B2
```

This is then the result:

```
pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 16126D3A3E5C1192 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 517590D9A8492E35 A6A19B38D3D831EF CEC384A8BF1700F8 A040830F7FAC5991 FC918B335044912E E131728675254D99 40C18E9EC07EE05F 7274A4DAE80D6BF5
[sudo] password for pst007x: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for pst007x: 
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.pGzLVgkAbN --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/atareao-atareao.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/diesch-testing.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ferramroberto-minitube.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/fossfreedom-rhythmbox-plugins.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/libreoffice-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/linrunner-tlp.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mc3man-trusty-media.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/menulibre-dev-devel.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/minecraft-installer-peeps-minecraft-installer.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/moka-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/myunity-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/nilarimogard-webupd8.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/nitrux-nitrux-artwork.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/nitrux-team-nitrux-artwork.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/noobslab-apps.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/noobslab-icons.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/noobslab-potenza.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/noobslab-themes.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/numix-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/otto-kesselgulasch-gimp.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/pinta-maintainers-pinta-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/pipelight-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ryochan7-antimicro.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/shimmerproject-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/synapse-core-testing.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/team-xbmc-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/team-xbmc-xbmc-nightly.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/thebernmeister-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/thefanclub-ubuntu-after-install.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/tiheum-equinox.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-mozilla-daily-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/wallch-wallch-4_0.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/webupd8team-gthumb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/webupd8team-java.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/webupd8team-themes.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/webupd8team-y-ppa-manager.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/wfg-0ad.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/xorg-edgers-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/xubuntu-dev-extras.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/xubuntu-dev-xfce-4_12.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/yorba-daily-builds.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 16126D3A3E5C1192 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 517590D9A8492E35 A6A19B38D3D831EF CEC384A8BF1700F8 A040830F7FAC5991 FC918B335044912E E131728675254D99 40C18E9EC07EE05F 7274A4DAE80D6BF5
gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/xubuntu-dev-extras.gpg': resource limit
gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/xubuntu-dev-xfce-4_12.gpg': resource limit
gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/yorba-daily-builds.gpg': resource limit
gpg: requesting key 437D05B5 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: requesting key C0B21F32 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: requesting key 3E5C1192 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: requesting key C0B21F32 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: requesting key A8492E35 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: requesting key D3D831EF from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: requesting key BF1700F8 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: requesting key 7FAC5991 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: requesting key 5044912E from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: requesting key 75254D99 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: requesting key C07EE05F from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: requesting key E80D6BF5 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 437D05B5: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: key C0B21F32: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: key 3E5C1192: "Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpgkeys: key CEC384A8BF1700F8 not found on keyserver
gpg: key C0B21F32: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: key A8492E35: "Opera Software Archive Automatic Signing Key 2013b <packager@opera.com>" not changed
gpg: key D3D831EF: "Xamarin Public Jenkins (auto-signing) <releng@xamarin.com>" not changed
gpg: key 7FAC5991: "Google, Inc. Linux Package Signing Key <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>" not changed
gpg: key 5044912E: "Dropbox Automatic Signing Key <linux@dropbox.com>" not changed
gpg: key 75254D99: "Launchpad test" not changed
gpg: key C07EE05F: "Launchpad PPA for Pascal de Bruijn" not changed
gpg: key E80D6BF5: "Launchpad cairo-dock" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 11
gpg:              unchanged: 11
```

**also this**

```
sudo apt-get update | grep "NO_PUBKEY" | awk '{ system("addgpg-apt "$21) }'
```

I have tried to restore default keys using Software & Updates utility, then trying all of the above again, but still the same issue... All keys  have gone.

Still the same issue... Any ideas would be appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: I also have this problem on a completely fresh vanilla install of Xubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be affected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/apt/+bug/1263540). If it is so, you can fix the problem easily by going to `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` and removing unused keys (e.g. keys for old PPAs that you have since deleted).

The bug occurs if there are more than 40 keys (*.gpg) in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`.

Comment: I deleted all contents in this folder and run { sudo launchpad-getkeys } then { sudo apt-get update }  .... this cleared the fault. Appreciated!

Comment: Also worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. Was wondering what's going on. Thank you very much.